# Необработанное исключение в ***.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++, visual-studio

При отладке вводил: `a,b,c,d`
При использовании `For` вместо `while (j<=n)` при отладке не входит в цикл
Вылетает при отладке в строке `c[j]=x[l+j];`
Подскажите в чем ошибка.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"  // не нужен,т.к. включен в stdafx.h
#include "conio.h"
#include "string.h"

void main()
{
    char x[100]={0},y[100]={0},c[14]={0},c1[14]={0};
    int a,b,n,i,j,l,k;
    bool w,e;

    gets_s(x); 
    n=0;
    l=0;
    k=0;
    w=1;
    for(i=0;x[i]!='\0';i++)

{
if (x[i]==',')  // слова разделены запятой
   {
       if (w==1)// 1 слово в паре
       {
         while (j<=n)                 // запись 1 слова в массив с
         {
             c[j]=x[l+j];   
         }
         w=0;
       }
       else          
       {
           for(j=0;j==n;j++)     // запись 2 слова в массив с1 
    {
        c1[j]=x[l+j];
        e=1;
        w=1;
    }
       }
       if(e==1)        // записана пара слов
       {                                     // далее запись массивов с1,с в Y
          memcpy(&y[k],c1,sizeof(c1));
          k=k+sizeof(c1);
          memcpy(&y[k],c,sizeof(c));
          k=k+sizeof(c);
         for (j=0;j==14;j++)      // обнуление массивов с и с1
         {
             c[j]=0;
             c1[j]=0;
         }
         e=0;
       }
    l=l+n;       // индекс начала слова
    n=0;         // длина слова+запятая
   }
 else
  n++;
}
   for(i=0;i==100;i++)
   {
       if(y[i]!='\0')          // если не пустой элемент массива
       {
           printf("%c",y[i]);     // вывод слов из массива Y на экран
       }
}
_getch();   // задержка экрана
};
```

Comment: А чему равны `j` и `l` в этой строчке?

Comment: перепишите это на с++ и оно скорее всего будет работать. А то, что Вы написали - это даже для чистого С жутко. (никто для строк не использует memcpy). Чувствую, автору вопроса нужно почитать мой ответ в [следующем вопросе](http://hashcode.ru/questions/155912/c-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=170022#170022)

Comment: @KoVadim, при подобных залепухах

    for(j=0;j==n;j++)     // запись 2 слова в массив с1 
    (дальше ще как минимум одна такая же есть)

никакое переписывание на любой язык не поможет.

Comment: если правильно переписать, то все будет хорошо:).

Comment: KoVadim, это не простая строка, а массив символов, если вы не знаете что делает gets_s(x).я копирую массив символов.и прежде чем комментировать хотя бы прочитайте ВСЕ и вдумайтесь. А всякую чушь не пишите.

Comment: @Berika321 - я прекрасно знаю, что делает gets_s - это поделка от майкрософт. Почему поделка? да потому что ее нет в стандарте.

Также, почитайте внимательно книги и узнайте, чем отличается массив символов от строки (подсказка - в строках обязательно наличие нулевого символа, в массивах - нет). Так что у Вас скорее всего строки, а не массивы:)

> и прежде чем комментировать хотя бы прочитайте ВСЕ и вдумайтесь.

я посмотрел и понял, что перед мной начинающий, сильно начинающий, который путается в коде.

а вместо `memcpy` все таки в данном случае лучше использовать `strncpy` и `strcpy`.

Comment: Добавлю, пожалуй. 

> если вы не знаете что делает gets_s(x)

Скажу даже более - Вы не знаете эту функцию. Посмотрите внимательно на ее [сигнатуру](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5x9wc7(v=vs.90).aspx):

    char *gets_s( 
       char *buffer,
       size_t sizeInCharacters
    );
Видите там второй параметр? А где он в Вашем коде? нет. Видимо, Вы вначале написали `gets`, но компилятор ругнулся, что "небезопасно". А почему компилятор проглотил? А это майкрософтовские шутки.

Comment: KoVadim, да я сильно начинающий.Но все что вы писали не имеет никакого отношения к моей проблеме, т.к. ваш вариант я опробовал ранее, результат был тот же(в Борланде)

Comment: @Berika321, если Вы хотите, что бы Вам быстро и качественно помогли, то кроме кода (а лучше его фрагментов, относящихся к делу (но, IMHO пока Вы с их выделением не справитесь)), **пишите условие задачи**, ОС и компилятор.


А также, **обязательно** что поступает на вход, что надо сделать, что Вы видите и что не нравится.

Желательно также краткое описание основных структур данных и их назначение в контексте Вашей задачи.

--

В противном случае, большинство участников ХК ни в чем разбираться не будет (если от скуки не возникнет желания поупражняться в телепатии).

Answer (score 3):

Решил вынести в отдельный ответ все мои комментарии, а то везде лимиты закончились.

Разберем код. Автор заявляет, что его код на с++. Но в заголовках С. В коде я не увидел ничего, что использовало бы преимущества С++ (`bool` видел, но это спорный вопрос). Поэтому, либо нужно поставить правильный заголовок, либо переписать код.

Теперь по коду.

```
void main()
```

такой заголовок на данный момент считается устаревшим. Крайне желательно писать так

```
int main()
```

О `gets_s(x);` я уже писал. В Вашем случае как минимум правильно писать так

```
gets_s(x, 100);
```

100 конечно лучше вынести в константы.

Следующий кусок

```
while (j<=n)                 // запись 1 слова в массив с
{
    c[j]=x[l+j];   
}
```

очень плохой кусок. если `j > n` - то он не выполниться. если условие истинно, то код внутри будет выполнятся бесконечно - код внутри цикла не изменяет условия. Это нужно осмыслить и переписать/дописать. Самое веселое, что на этот момент, переменная `j` не инициализирована. А поэтому, что там будет - одной оси ведомо. Условие может срабатывать в зависимости от фазы Луны.

Смотрим дальше.

```
for(j=0;j==n;j++)     // запись 2 слова в массив с1 
{
    c1[j]=x[l+j];
    e=1;
    w=1;
}
```

переменные `e` и `w` независимы от цикла. Их можно смело вынести за пределы цикла. В результате в цикле остается копирование массива. `memcpy( c1, x+l, n);`  в помощь. Правда перед этим я бы проверил, что там не будет выхода за пределы массива.

ещё:

```
memcpy(&y[k],c1,sizeof(c1));
k=k+sizeof(c1);
memcpy(&y[k],c,sizeof(c));
k=k+sizeof(c);
```

если я правильно понимаю, то эти две пары строк просто дописывают найденные слова в новый массив. Раз используете C, тогда может [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) - она добавляет строку в конец другой? Писали бы на чистом с++, то было бы что то в стиле `y += c1; y+= c;` или `y.push_back(c1); y.push_back(c);`

Но вот с этим y мне не понятно. По одной части кода - это просто массив символов, по другой - это массив строк. Определитесь.

дальше - ещё:

```
for (j=0;j==14;j++)      // обнуление массивов с и с1
{
    c[j]=0;
    c1[j]=0;
 }
```

есть чудесная функция [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/). Правда, в ней важно не спутать второй и третий параметр.

```
memset(c, 0, 14);
memset(c, 0, 14);
```

в Вашем коде есть ещё одна проблема - там выход за пределы массива. Там то элемента  с индексом 14 нет.

теперь - "закат Солнца вручную"

```
for(i=0;i==100;i++)
{
    if(y[i]!='\0')          // если не пустой элемент массива
    {
        printf("%c",y[i]);     // вывод слов из массива Y на экран
    }
}
```

почему вручную? да потому что можно было бы написать так

```
printf("%s", y);
```

или даже `puts(y);`

Но там есть засада. Там массив символов, в котором есть нулевые символы. Я бы использовал двумерный массив. Плюс, не проверяется, а не длинее ли 14 символов очередное слово.

Также в коде объявлены переменные `a` и `b`, которые не используются.

Теперь ответы на вопросы:

> > При использовании For вместо while (j<=n) при отладке не входит в цикл
> > Вылетает при отладке в строке c[j]=x[l+j];

В принципе, выше я уже разобрал это. Почему вылетает? просто значение j может быть любое число. А так как массив `c` и `x` не безграничны, то с большой вероятностью будет выход за пределы массива. Что делать? инициализировать переменные. Все, в обязательном порядке.

---

Я пытался понять, что делает код и попробовал переписать его на с++ (хотя специалисты скажут, что это ещё не совсем чистый с++, но я знаю. я сознательно это написал)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::string delimiter = ",";
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = s.substr(0, pos);
        words.push_back(token);
        s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    if (!s.empty()) {
        words.push_back(s);
    }
    if (words.size() == 0) {
        std::cout << "no input, no output";
        return 0;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < words.size() - 1; i+=2) {
        std::cout << words[i+1] << " " << words[i] << " ";
    }
    if (words.size() % 2 == 1) {
        std::cout << words[words.size()-1];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Кстати, в Вашем коде я не увидел явной проверки на то, что пользователь введет нечетное кол-во слов или вообще ничего не введет.

---

p.s. Если кого то повторил, не обижайтесь, я просто просматривал код сверху вниз.

Comment: +1, но `gets_s(x)` — вполне [нормальная конструкция](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5b5x9wc7.aspx). Размер массива в этой перегрузке поставляет «шаблонная магия». И доступ к неинициализированной переменной — UB.

Comment: о да. Нормальная. Если массив статический. Если же он динамический, то хорошенькое себе UB. Я с функциями вида `*_s` намучился, пока не выискивал все. особенно хорош подарок в этом случае с функцией `sprinf_s`. Она требует, что бы для параметров типа `%s`  в списке аргументов указывалась ещё и длина.

Comment: @KoVadim: что-то не так с вашим кунг-фу: <http://ideone.com/2oN4V8>, <http://ideone.com/umkUbf>. Никакого UB, просто не компилируется.

Comment: очень интересно, когда чисто си функции заворачиваются теплейтами. Да и ещё на не майкрософтомском компиляторе. Эпичненько. А для чистого си кода они будут работать? :)

По факту - не знаю, это было в 2010 студии. Падало. Со страшной силой. А начальство прижимало.  Поменял все ручками, находя поиском все вхождения. Скорее всего где то и перестарался. Может потому, что у меня там вперемешку был и плюсовый и чисто си код?


с другой стороны, дико это как то, что есть подобные функции. Особенно в случае `*scanf_s`.

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте индексы - почти наверняка есть выход за пределы массива(ов).

Comment: прочитайте в самом верху. я ввожу a,b,c,d выполняется вход в цикл while затем ошибка.а массив у меня не на 1 элемент

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно строку введенную с консоли, разбить на слова, а слова определять по наличию запятой и потом записать эти слова в массив так, чтобы каждому индексу соответствовало слово.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

void main()
{
  char input[10100];
  char words[101][101] = {{'\0'}, {'\0'}}; //максимум 100 слов по 100 символов в каждом
  char* bword = input; //начало каждого слова
  char* pdelim; //позиция каждой запятой
  int i = 0; //количество слов
  gets(input);

  do
  {
    pdelim = strchr(bword, ',');
    if(pdelim) {
      strncpy(words[i++], bword, pdelim-bword);
      bword = pdelim+1;
    }
    else
      strncpy(words[i], bword, strlen(bword));
  } while(pdelim);

  for(int j=0;j <= i;j++)
    printf("%s\n",words[j]);

  getchar();  
}
```

Comment: просто поменять местами пары слов=)попробую разобрать ваш код и переписать под мою задачу

Comment: Опишите точнее задачу. Нужно реверс строки, или менять местами два слова, то есть, если на "входе a,b,c,d", то нужно сделать badc? И слова должны записываться в массив без запятых? В общем, в моем коде каждое слово соответствует своему индексу массива. То есть, вы можете и запятые добавить и реверс сделать или что-то ещё. 
 

    for(int j=0;j < i;j++)
      {
        char temp1[101];
        *temp1 = *words[j];
        *words[j] = *words[j+1];
        *words[++j] = *temp1;
      }

Это пример кода, который меняет a b c d на b a d c . Добавьте его в мой код перед for, который выводит массив.

Comment: разочарую вас, но этот код не работает. Этот "якобы обмен" на самом то деле обменяет только первые символы в строках.

Comment: @strol, наверное вместо этого цикла правильно было бы написать функцию и вызывать ее.

Кстати, а зачем такие пляски с temp? Массив там не нужен, достаточно памяти для одного символа.

Comment: for(int j=0;j < i;j++)
  {
    char temp[101];
    strcpy(temp, words[j]);
    strcpy(words[j], words[j+1]);
    strcpy(words[++j], temp);
  }
В общем, вот рабочий вариант. А как без temp?

Comment: Ну, в прошлом-то варианте (судя по коду) вы попарно обменивали i символов в массиве `char words[]`, там для обмена нужен 1 символ. 

А в новом коде Вы попарно обмениваете местами строки, адресуемые массивом указателей (всего i указателей).

Это вообще-то другой код.

--

Сейчас глянул на код в Вашем ответе.

После копирования (strncpy()) нужно нолик в конец нового слова добавлять. Из [доки](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xdsywd25%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

    a null character is not appended automatically to the copied string

А что и где Вы обмениваете-то?

Comment: Не знаю. Автор говорил, что нужно пары слов менять местами. Вот и менял. Ещё код :
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main()
{
  char input[1024],* words[128], *pword;
  int i = 0;
  gets(input); 
  while (pword = strtok(i ? NULL : input, ","))
    words[i++] = pword;

  for(int j=0;j < i-1;j++)
  {
    char *temp = words[j];
    words[j] = words[j+1];
    words[++j] = temp;
  }

  for(int j=0;j < i;j++)
    printf("%s\n",words[j]);

  getchar();  
}

Comment: @avp, А почему в строчке `words[j] = words[j+1];` если ставлю `j++` вместо `j+1` и в следующей строчке `words[++j] = temp;` ставлю  j вместо `++j`, то j как будто не инкрементировалась в предыдущей строке и поэтому приходится сначала писать j+1 в первой строчке и j++ во второй. С чем это связано?
@KoVadim, а где об этом почитать можно? А то нашел только, что в паскале это логическая ошибка, а за С++ ничего.

Comment: у Вас j - параметр цикла и Вы пытаетесь его модифицировать внутри цикла. Это плохой прием и обычно он не работает. Нормальные компиляторы на такое ругаются.